# Memory issues in a Cloud Storage Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have deployed a storage trigger cloud function that needs more memory. While deploying the GCF, I have deployed in the following manner with the appropriate flags.

`gcloud functions deploy GCF_name--runtime python37 --trigger-resource bucket_name --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize --timeout 540s --memory 8192MB`

But I observed in the google cloud console, the memory utilization map is not going beyond 2GB. And in the logs I am getting this error,  `Function execution took 34566 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'` which happens because of memory shortage. Can I get some help on this.

[image: Image Utilization graph]

**Edited**

The application uploads text files to the storage that contains certain number of samples. Each file is read when it is uploaded to the storage and the data appended to a pre existing file. The total number of samples will be maximum of 75600002. That's why I need 8GB data. Its giving the connection error while appending the data to the file.

```
def write_to_file(filename,data,write_meta = False,metadata = []):
    file1 = open('/tmp/'+ filename,"a+")
    if write_meta:
        file1.write(":".join(metadata))
        file1.write('\n')
    file1.write(",".join(data.astype(str)))
    file1.close()
```

The memory utilisation map was the same after every upload.

Comment: First, is this behaviour random or every time you get the `connection error`. Then If you can share more detail of your implementation like why you need 8GB for your cloud function, it might help.

Comment: @MBHAPhoenix, I have edited question. Hope its more clear

Comment: 1) How have you determined this to be a connection error caused by memory? 2) You do not include details/code related to connections. Just code that writes to **/tmp**. Edit your question and provide a reproducible example that demonstrates your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a file to `/tmp` which is an in-memory filesystem. So start by deleting that file when you finish uploading it. In fact those:

> Files that you write consume memory available to your function, and sometimes persist between invocations. Failing to explicitly delete these files may eventually lead to an out-of-memory error and a subsequent cold start.

Ref : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#always_delete_temporary_files

Comment: I am deleting the files using `os.remove`.